# Review queue item order

Tags: feature-request, review, top-bar

Currently item order in review page is differ from the equvivalent list from review popup:

> [image: review order]

In the picture above item order for page view is:

1. Triage
2. Documentation
3. First Posts
4. Late Answers

For popup menu:

1. First Posts
2. Late Answers
3. Triage
4. Documentation

What's the reason to not make them same? Is it just was overlooked?

Comment: Cross-site duplication in MSO with answer: [Review queues drop down list - review types are ordered by what logic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346610/2451726)

Comment: @Arulkumar thanx for link, but I still can't understand what's the reason to use different ordering. Why muscle-memory is worth for popup, but not for page view?

Answer (score 3):

Just reproducing [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346651/616460) from [that same question on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346610/616460):

> They're ordered *first* by the minimum reputation needed to access the queue, and *then* alphabetically by the name of the queue.
>
> The purpose of this ordering is to keep the list as consistent as possible *until your privilege-level changes* - the hope is that folks use this as their primary means of accessing the queues, and as such we're not forcing reviewers to override their muscle-memory every time they go to access a specific queue - a worthy design goal for a menu that appears on just about every page of the site.

Answer (score 1):

The page lists the queues by number of items to review, descending. (Presumably to point out where the most help is needed.)

The pop-up has the list in a static order.

As this only applies to the new Stack Overflow design, though, this question is probably better off at [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Top bar was rolled out to all localized SO sites yesterday. I.e. it reflect not only English SO. That's why I posted it on MSE.